# Connected component program produces incorrect output

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, graph, connected-components

I am working on a program which takes in a 5x5 array of characters and finds the longest list of same characters, connected meaning adjacent either up, down, left, or to the right of (meaning NO diagonals). However the output is off by 1, giving 6  instead of the correct 7, with the input:

```
a b c c b
a c b c c
c a a b a
b b a a c
a a a b a
```

**Can anybody help me find what my error in my code is?** **(MY CODE IS BELOW)**

*DETAILS:*  the missing character is at index [3][3] (index starting at 0). When I tested my `look()` function, it worked properly, when I passed it 3 for row and 2 for col,and it added [3][3] to the final vector to be returned, but I think that something did not pan out right with the recursion.

**I have already worked on debugging this, to no success, you can see the debug prints in my code.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;
char grid[5][5];
bool seen[5][5];
int cnt = 1;
int maxn = 0;

vector<pair<int, int>> look(int row, int col)
{
    //
    vector<pair<int, int >> node_list;
    if (row != 0)
        if (grid[row - 1][col] == grid[row][col])
            if (!seen[row - 1][col])
                node_list.push_back(make_pair(row - 1, col));
    if (row != 4)
        if (grid[row + 1][col] == grid[row][col])
            if (!seen[row+1][col])
                node_list.push_back(make_pair(row + 1, col));
    if (col != 0)
        if (grid[row][col - 1] == grid[row][col])
            if (!seen[row][col-1])
                node_list.push_back(make_pair(row, col - 1));
    if (col != 4)
        if (grid[row][col + 1] == grid[row][col])
            if (!seen[row][col+1])
                node_list.push_back(make_pair(row, col + 1));
    if (binary_search(node_list.begin(), node_list.end(), make_pair(2, 2)))
        cout << "HAPPENED^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^" << "\n";
    return node_list;
}

void search(int row, int col)
{
    for (pair<int, int> a : look(row, col))
    {
        if (!seen[a.first][a.second])
        {
            seen[a.first][a.second] = true;
            cnt++;
            cout << "COUNTED and now SEARCHING " << a.first << " " << a.second << "\n";
            cout << "search about to be called on " << a.first << " " << a.second << "\n";
            search(a.first, a.second);
        }
    }
    if (cnt > maxn)
        maxn = cnt;
    cout << "CNT: " << cnt << "\n";
    cnt = 1;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            cin >> grid[i][j];
            seen[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (!seen[i][j])
            {
                cout << "INITIALLY SEARCHING: " << i << " " << j << "\n";
                seen[i][j] = true;
                cout << "search about to be called on " << i << " " << j << "\n";
                search(i, j);
            }
            else
                cout << "NO INITIAL SEARCH, SEEN: " << i << " " << j << "\n";
        }
    }
    cout << maxn << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What should be the output whe i pass [3][2] ?

Comment: That is not the actual input, it is the test input that I passed the look() function, with 3 as the row and 2 as the col. It outputs 2 2, 4 2, and 3 3.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger so you can go through the program step by step? This should allow you to find the point where it does something that you did not expect it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `search` recursively but also unconditionally resetting `cnt` at the end of it.

This issue can be demonstrated on a simple "board" with only 3 characters:

```
a a a
```

Assume that we start `search` with the middle `a`. It calls `look` and gets told to inspect two other places: The `a` to the left and the `a` to the right. `search` then calls itself, let's say with the left `a`. `cnt` is `2` at this point and both the left and middle `a` have their `seen` set to `true`. This second recursive `search` call again asks `look` to find nearby `a`, but this time they are all already seen. So the second `search` finishes up, sets `maxn` to `2` and **resets `cnt` to `1`**. Now we are back at the first level of recursion and proceed to the `a` on the right. Needless to say, we have discarded the one time we counted `a` on the left.

The problem here is that you didn't clearly separate the "recursively search nearby fields" from "start a search from this point". The last two lines of your current `search` belong to the latter but not the former. I would suggest this:

```
void searchRecursive(int row, int col)
{
    for (pair<int, int> a : look(row, col))
    {
        if (!seen[a.first][a.second])
        {
            seen[a.first][a.second] = true;
            cnt++;
            searchRecursive(a.first, a.second);
        }
    }
}

void startSearchFrom(int row, int col)
{
    cnt = 1;
    seen[i][j] = true;
    searchRecursive(row, col);
    if (cnt > maxn)
        maxn = cnt;
    cout << "CNT: " << cnt << "\n";
}
```

This separates these concerns nicely.

A further improvement would be to get rid of all the global state. It is not immediately obvious (although true) that your algorithm works correctly despite `seen` never being reset, and verifying that `cnt` is used correctly requires keeping in mind *all* places where it is used. If every `searchRecursive` instead returned how many unseen locations it found, it would be trivial to verify that the result is correct.